# Sqlite выборка разного количества строк с использованием order

Tags: sql, база-данных, sqlite

Есть две таблицы `targets` и `freq_check`. Сейчас запросом выбираю три максимальных значения `check_id` для разных `target_id`:

```sql
SELECT target_id, check_id FROM freq_check a 
WHERE a.id in 
(SELECT id FROM freq_check b WHERE b.target_id = a.target_id ORDER BY b.check_id DESC LIMIT 3);
```

Получаю список из максимальных значений с лимитом 3, но дело в том, что для каждой цели (`target_id`) нужен разный лимит, который прописан в таблице `targets`.

Например, для `id = 1` из `targets` (соответствует `target_id` из `freq_check`) и `freq_num = 2` нужно выводить две строки из запроса выше.

То есть в зависимости от значения `freq_num` в таблице `targets` выводить из запроса выше для каждого `check_id` свой лимит. Для `freq_num = 2` — `LIMIT 2`, для `freq_num = 10` — `LIMIT 10` и т. д.

Никак не пойму как правильно написать запрос. Такое возможно?

Answer (score 0):

В версии 3.25 и выше можно использовать оконные функции. Не уверен, что
это самое быстродействующее решение, но оно работает:

```sql
WITH result(target_id, check_id, freq_num, row_num) AS (
  SELECT f.target_id
       , f.check_id
       , t.freq_num
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY target_id ORDER BY check_id DESC) AS row_num
    FROM freq_check AS f
    JOIN targets AS t
      ON f.target_id = t.id
)
SELECT target_id, check_id
  FROM result
 WHERE row_num <= freq_num
;
```

Comment: Дело в том, что sqlite работает в связке с Unity и на данный момент я использую версию 3.11.0. Обновить sqlite будет проблематично.